# Does there exist a constant $M\gt 0$ such that for every entire polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis

Does it exist a constant $M\gt 0$ such that for every entire polynomial, we have $$\max_{z \in C}\vert z^{-1}-P(z) \vert \ge M$$ Where $C$ denote the unit circle.

Comment: What's entire polynomials?

Comment: $P(z)=a_nz^n+...+a_1z+a_0$

Comment: A polynomial is automatically entire...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In fact $$\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{{2\pi}}|e^{-it}-P(e^{it})|^2\,dt=1+\sum|a_n|^2\ge1,$$hence you can take  $M=1$.

Comment: How did you simplify the integral on LHS?

Comment: @Vim Parseval...